# A Kindle Fire Giveaway... Let's Discuss

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We will have 5 Kindle Fires to give away over the course of a week in the near future. Android blogger [AndroidGuys](http://www.androidguys.com/) will help us promote this campaign. A rough draft of the promotion:

AndroidGuys asks 5 questions on Monday. The next Monday, the 5 users that have best answered the questions win the prizes.

Up for discussion:

- What should the questions be?
- Should the 'best answerer' be the person whose answer gets the
  most upvotes **or** the person who provides the answer accepted by the asker (AndroidGuys)?
- Again, what should the questions be!?

Possible Questions (a place to start):

1. "What is the biggest difference between the Kindle Fire and the iPad?"
2. "What should I tell a friend who has Android battery problems?"
3. "What can we expect in the next round of Android releases and should I wait until 2012 to buy one?"
4. "... Android 4.0 ..."
5. "What does [the graphic published here](http://www.businessinsider.com/the-one-chart-you-need-to-see-to-understand-mobile-2011-11?utm_source=#frankguillen&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=FrankGuillen%20Buzz) mean for the future of Android?"

Which of these are unacceptable (for those of you new to the site, [please see here](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq#questions))? Which questions should be reworded? What question isn't listed here that you think should be included?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea, but the proposed questions have the problems that Matthew Read has pointed out.

Would it be better to perhaps choose some of the currently *unanswered* questions *here*, find the more interesting ones, and promote those?

1. You have real questions from real people
2. Little chance of being closed as subjective, dupe, or off-topic, because presumably that would already have happened
3. Someone might actually get a useful answer to their thus far unanswerable question

Answer (score 3):

I think only #2 is acceptable, though it might be closed as a dupe.  #1 and #5 are way too subjective, #3 is an off-topic shopping advice question, and #4 isn't a question :P.  (Note we don't take speculative questions either, which applies to most questions about 4.0 and the Fire right now.)

If a contest wants to use questions here I think they still need to be real questions, real problems, asked and answerable from a user's perspective.

Comment: Ugh. Beat me to it.