# What Old(er) Unanswered Questions are Still Relevant Today?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Please answer if you've asked or if you see an [**unanswered Android question**](https://android.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) that you think is a good question today and will remain a useful question in 6 months.

Once we identify a few, we'll consider offering up [a physical bounty](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/a-kindle-fire-giveaway-lets-discuss)!

Thx for the help!

Comment: I think that one week is to short to produce quality answers for long-time unanswered questions. 3-4 weeks would be better and also attract more people to the contest.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a few:

- [Text-to-speech reader for Google Voice SMS text messages?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/text-to-speech-reader-for-google-voice-sms-text-messages) (June)
- [Android Email application dropping profile](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/android-email-application-dropping-profile) (December 2010)
- [Multiple USB Storage Devices on Honeycomb](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/multiple-usb-storage-devices-on-honeycomb) (April)

Answer (score 4):

I really like the idea, I think there are a lot!!

Here there are some of them:

[Block all sounds going out through speaker when headphone connected](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10996/block-all-sounds-going-out-through-speaker-when-headphone-connected)

[How can I fix the WiFi button or prevent WiFi errors when turning it off and back on?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4504/how-can-i-fix-the-wifi-button-or-prevent-wifi-errors-when-turning-it-off-and-bac)

Answer (score 3):

There are many that are good questions and also very hard to answer, generally due to obscurity.  There are some that seem more broadly useful if solved, though.  One that stood out:

- [Samsung Galaxy 5 Wi-fi stops working: "ar6000 driver fails to load"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12883/samsung-galaxy-5-wi-fi-stops-working-ar6000-driver-fails-to-load) (August)

And a newer one:

- [How can I download email attachments only when requested?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/download-only-email-headers-and-body-text-no-attachment) (October)

Answer (score 3):

This is great. Any way we can create a system message or do something else to nudge users to dig thru the old unanswered questions and submit them here? Or how about... can you sort old unanswered questions by view count (I can't) to see what garners interest today?

I'd like to maybe nominate 10 or 15 old questions for this initiative & attach a "bounty" -- answer a question, throw your name in the hat for a Kindle Fire.

Also, I don't see why moderators can't be eligible here.

Comment: Everyone can search for unanswered questions by view count: [Not closed questions without answers and more than 600 views](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0+is%3Aquestion+closed%3A0+views%3A600&submit=search) or [Not closed questions with unaccepted answers and more than 4k(!) views](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A0+is%3Aquestion+closed%3A0+views%3A4000&submit=search)

Comment: I'll see about putting up a system message.

Answer (score 3):

In going back through the unanswered questions, the following twelve seemed to be more likely to garner a response or interest from average user types.

1. [Why does a single MMS message show up as three separate download
   buttons?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3284/why-does-a-single-mms-message-show-up-as-three-separate-download-buttons)
2. [How can I download email attachments only when requested?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/how-can-i-download-email-attachments-only-when-requested)
3. [Multiple USB Storage Devices on Honeycomb](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/multiple-usb-storage-devices-on-honeycomb)
4. [Text-to-speech reader for Google Voice SMS text messages?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/text-to-speech-reader-for-google-voice-sms-text-messages)
5. [Google Latitude and multiple devices How to prevent location jumping?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15012/google-latitude-and-multiple-devices-how-to-prevent-location-jumping)
6. [How can I download email attachments only when requested?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/how-can-i-download-email-attachments-only-when-requested)
7. [Multiple update notifications from Android Market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14934/marketplace-offers-downloads-in-notifications-but-when-i-tap-notification-none-a)
8. [How can data on an unrooted phone be backed up?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12470/how-can-data-on-an-unrooted-phone-be-backed-up)
9. [HTML signature in Gmail app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15552/html-signature-in-gmail-app)
10. [How can I prevent my screen from turning off while on a phone call?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13343/how-can-i-prevent-my-screen-from-turning-off-while-on-a-phone-call)
11. [Dialer app becoming too slow and less responsive](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15317/dialer-app-becoming-too-slow-and-less-responsive)
12. [How can I change the naming convention of the stock camera/gallery app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13954/how-can-i-change-the-naming-convention-of-the-stock-camera-gallery-app)

Comment: Any way we can get dates in parantheses next to these questions?