# Unanswered Questions: Please Vote

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Below are <s>15</s> 30 unanswered questions that will soon be included in a contest to win 1 of 5 Kindle Fires. See information about the contest [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/a-kindle-fire-giveaway-lets-discuss) and [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/691/what-older-unanswered-questions-are-still-relevant-today).

Please **upvote** the below "answers" if you think the question is a good evergreen question that you want answered.

Please **downvote** the question if you think it is outdated, already answered, or flawed in some way that makes it inappropriate for this contest. Feel free to add notes to an answer to explain your opinion.

Please **add** any old(er) unanswered question that you want answered or that you think the world wants answered. (See here for: [Unanswered Android questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes); [Not closed questions without answers and more than 600 views](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers:0%20is:question%20closed:0%20views:600&submit=search); [Not closed questions with unaccepted answers and more than 4k(!) views](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasaccepted:0%20is:question%20closed:0%20views:4000&submit=search))

Thanks for your help! I'd like to get this contest started the Monday after Thanksgiving (11/28).

Comment: How can I prevent the auto convert to comment? I'd like to post it as an answer...

Comment: @Flow - Use the convention seen below. If that doesn't work, the question likely doesn't include the minimum character count to be considered an answer. In this case, I'd suggest adding a few words to the question title.

Comment: @Flow - I've added the q as an answer here: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/733/6852

Answer (score 11):

Q: **How can data on an unrooted phone be backed up?** ([Aug 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12470/how-can-data-on-an-unrooted-phone-be-backed-up))

Answer (score 8):

I'll throw one of my own in:

Q: **How can I prevent Google Talk from disconnecting?** ([Jan 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4345/how-can-i-prevent-google-talk-from-disconnecting))

Answer (score 8):

Q: **How can I prevent applications from running on startup?** ([Sep 2010](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/158/how-can-i-prevent-applications-from-running-on-startup))

Answer (score 6):

Q: **How can I fix the WiFi button or prevent WiFi errors when turning it off and back on?** ([Jan 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4504/how-can-i-fix-the-wifi-button-or-prevent-wifi-errors-when-turning-it-off-and-bac))

Answer (score 5):

Q: **Dialer app becoming too slow and less responsive** ([Nov 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15317/dialer-app-becoming-too-slow-and-less-responsive))

Comment: Think you've mis-linked this one

Comment: @GAThrawn - fixed! thx.

Answer (score 4):

Q: **Marketplace offers downloads in notifications but when I tap notification none are available.** ([Oct 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14934/marketplace-offers-downloads-in-notifications-but-when-i-tap-notification-none-a))

Answer (score 4):

Q: **Text-to-speech reader for Google Voice SMS text messages?** ([June 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/text-to-speech-reader-for-google-voice-sms-text-messages))

Answer (score 4):

Q: **How can I prevent my screen from turning off while on a phone call?** ([Sep 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13343/how-can-i-prevent-my-screen-from-turning-off-while-on-a-phone-call))

Answer (score 4):

Q: **Samsung Galaxy 5 Wi-fi stops working: “ar6000 driver fails to load."** ([Aug 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12883/samsung-galaxy-5-wi-fi-stops-working-ar6000-driver-fails-to-load))

Answer (score 4):

Q: **How to block all sounds going out through speaker when headphone is connected?** ([June 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10996/block-all-sounds-going-out-through-speaker-when-headphone-connected))

Answer (score 3):

Q: **How can I change the naming convention of the stock camera/gallery app?** ([Sept 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13954/how-can-i-change-the-naming-convention-of-the-stock-camera-gallery-app))

Answer (score 3):

Q: **Google Latitude and multiple devices - How to prevent location jumping?** ([Oct 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15012/google-latitude-and-multiple-devices-how-to-prevent-location-jumping))

Answer (score 3):

Q: **How to flush/clear DNS cache on an Android phone?** ([Sep 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12962/flush-clear-dns-cache))

Answer (score 2):

Q: **Is it possible to set a HTML signature in the Android Gmail app?** ([Nov 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15552/html-signature-in-gmail-app))

Answer (score 2):

Q: **Can I use multiple USB storage devices on Honeycomb?** ([Apr 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/multiple-usb-storage-devices-on-honeycomb))

Answer (score 2):

Q: **Why does a single MMS message show up as 3 separate download buttons?** ([Dec 2010](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3284/why-does-a-single-mms-message-show-up-as-three-separate-download-buttons))

Answer (score 2):

Q: **How can I download email attachments only when requested?** ([Oct 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/how-can-i-download-email-attachments-only-when-requested))

Answer (score 2):

Q: **Why is my Android email application dropping my profile?** ([Dec 2010](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/android-email-application-dropping-profile))

Answer (score 2):

Q: **How to add an Android packet data shortcut in 2.3.3 Gingerbread?** ([Aug 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12960/android-packet-data-shortcut))

Answer (score 2):

Q: **Media volume issues on a rooted Samsung Galaxy 1551.** ([Sep 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13302/media-volume-issues))

Answer (score 2):

Q: **How do I change the name of my Android device without rooting?** ([Sep 13](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-do-i-change-the-name-of-my-android-device))

Answer (score 2):

Q: **Why does my Droid X (Gingerbread) turn itself on automatically?** ([Jun 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10082/droid-x-turns-itself-on-automatically))

Answer (score 1):

Q: **How can I mount a USB flash drive on my Acer Iconia?** ([Sep 2011](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13094/how-can-i-mount-a-usb-flash-drive-on-my-acer-iconia))